# Deep Learning: How to deal with missing label values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I need to use deep learning to classify an input vector into 10 categories (numbers from 0 to 9). To do so, I have two training datasets: one labeled (n=9000) and another unlabeled (n=21000).

Should I just train my model with the labeled train dataset or use it to first predict the labels of the unlabeled train dataset and then train the model using all the train data? What other approaches would you suggest? Would it be possible to use an autoencoder?

I have already tried to use the labeled train data to predict the labels for my unlabeled data. However, I haven't reached a good accuracy. I am wondering if this is caused by the imputed data or the model.

```
###Load data
train_labeled = pd.read_hdf("train_labeled.h5", "train")
train_unlabeled = pd.read_hdf("train_unlabeled.h5", "train")
test = pd.read_hdf("test.h5", "test")

X_labeled = np.array(train_labeled.iloc[:,1:])
X_unlabeled = np.array(train_unlabeled)
y_labeled = np.array(train_labeled.iloc[:,0])

###Impute missing values
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
neigh.fit(X_labeled, y_labeled) 
y_unlabeled = neigh.predict(X_unlabeled)

###Combine data
X = np.concatenate((X_labeled, X_unlabeled), axis=0)
y = np.concatenate((y_labeled, y_unlabeled), axis=0)

###Split train and test data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size = 0.8)

###Create model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
layers.BatchNormalization(),
layers.Dense(80, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)),
layers.Dense(80, activation=tf.nn.relu),  
layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

###Train model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=20,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: As it relates to theory more than actual coding, this might be a better question for the sister sites [stats.se] or [datascience.se]

Answer (score 1):

One approach to deal with your data situation (small labeled + large unlabeled data) is called semi-supervised learning.

Directly using your model trained on small labeled training data has its own problems. If your initial model accuracy is not good enough or your labeled training data is biased then you will see the errors propagate to your generated labels.

Getting semi-supervised learning working acceptably is quite challenging, I recommend looking at Ladder networks, Pseudo-labeling and metric learning papers to try more principled approaches.